# awk or sed to display output one per line based of search pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following file: searching for "LC"(2nd search pattern) gives more that one line output, i need to process it to provide one per line repeating 1st search pattern adjacent to it.

```
Schedule Name:       Today

  Schedule Type:       Standard
  Active:              yes
  Effective date:      01/24/2014 11:17:05
  Client Encrypt:      no
  LC/CY/Custmr:  EU         NY  Cindy
                 BU         CA  Victor
                 GU         MI  Bob
  Include:
Schedule Name:       Tomorrow

  Schedule Type:       Standard
  Active:              yes
  Effective date:      01/26/2014 11:17:05
  Client Encrypt:      no
  LC/CY/Custmr:  MU         LA  Martha
                 EU         CA  Sam
  Include:
Schedule Name:       Yesterday

  Schedule Type:       Standard
  Active:              no
  Effective date:      01/21/2014 11:17:05
  Client Encrypt:      no
  LC/CY/Custmr:  NV         IL  Joe

  Include:
```

Desired Output

```
Cindy    Today
Victor   Today
Bob      Today
Martha   Tomorrow
Sam      Tomorrow
```

Now I want to get `Schedule Name` i.e Today, Tomorrow along with `Customer name` which is the 4th field if `Active` is `yes`. So the output should be:

```
cat billing | 
    awk '/Schedule Name/ || /Active:/ || /Loc/,/^$/' | 
    grep -v '^$'
```

A blank line is after Loc before Include, So I am trying get me all data till you find a blank line and then grep -v blank line, It works fine if I try without awking Schedule name and Active, but doesn't work along with these 2 patter searches.

I am using below code which is pretty slow.

```
for pol in `cat /tmp/Active_Policies`
do
        count=`sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist $pol -U | awk '/HW\/OS\/Client:/,/Include:/' | grep -v "Include:" | wc -l`
        if [ $count -gt 0 ]
        then
                first=`sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist $pol -U | awk '/HW\/OS\/Client:/,/Include:/' | grep -v "Include:" | awk '{print $4}' | head -1`
                echo "$first    $pol" >> /tmp/Clients_Policies_$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
                counter=1
                for client in `sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist $pol -U | awk '/HW\/OS\/Client:/,/Include:/' | grep -v "Include:" | awk '{print $3}' | sed '1d;$d'`
                do
                        ((counter = counter + 1))
                        if [ $counter -le $count ]
                        then
                                echo "$client   $pol" >> /tmp/Clients_Policies_$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
                        fi
                done
        fi
done
```

Comment: The post doesn't show the output I am looking for, Let me know in case of any doubt.

Comment: We can achieve it from different method, but to reduce the complexity of the entire code i would want single awk to perform this task.

Comment: 1) what have you tried? read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; 2) what does [tag:ssh] have to do with this?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your post, show us what you have so far and explain which part of this is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
awk '
    BEGIN{OFS = "\t"}
    /Schedule Name:/{s = $NF}
    /Active:/{a = $2}
    /:|^$/&&!/LC\//{next}
    a == "yes"{print $NF, s}
    ' file
```

Or **sed**

```
sed '
    /Schedule Name:/! d
    s/.*:\s\+//
    :1
    N
    /Active:/! b1
    /yes/! d
    :2
    $! N
    /Include:/d
    /LC\//!{/:\|^$/b2;}
    s/\s*\n.*\s\(\S\+\)\s*/\n\1/
    s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\t\1/p
    s/.*\t//
    t2
    ' file
```

**sed** version 2:

```
sed -n '
    /Schedule Name:/! d
    s/.*:\s\+//
    h
    :1
    n
    /Active:\s*no/d
    /LC\//!b1
    :2
    s/.*\s\(\S*\)\s*/\1/
    G
    s/\n/\t/p
    n
    /^\s*$\|Include:/! b2
    ' file
```

Comment: Thanks, However it doesn't give me any output.

Comment: @Sid I have tested it on example date and it produce output as required. Try to remove trailing spaces by `sed -i '/\s\+$/s///' file` before

Comment: Yes it did, actually too much data was taking a lot of time, do you think there could be any other way than awk? Also I have a small issue, as i mentioned above In few schedule entries there are more than one entry for Loc/City/Customer, So i wanted Schedule name to be repeated for each Customer as mentioned above. In addition to this I have another issue, I get these entries by egrep "Schedule Name|Active|Loc", and I just realized that it sweeps any entry more than 1 for Loc which is a problem.

Comment: @Sid Do not use **egrep** at all. The **awk** script is enough alone. For your data **sed** script may be quicker a little but not too much.

Comment: thanks for the reply, let me get the data from awk, I will have to match Schedule Name, Active and most importantly Loc and for Loc I will have to get the data till next line as single Loc will have multiple entries, so let me try

Comment: I changed egrep to below command, it works fine for Schedule Name and Active, However if there are more than 1 Loc entry in the file I am trying to fetch all, It doesn't seem to work.

cat billing | awk '/Schedule Name/ || /Active:/ || /Loc/,/^$/' | grep -v '^$' 

A blank line is after Loc, So I am trying get me all data till you find a blank line and then grep -v blank line, It works fine if I try without awking Schedule name and Active, but doesn't work along with these 2 patter searches.

Comment: @Sid You need not use any additional command except script in answer. If there are extra lines which you want to exclude from output please show full  data example

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I edited the original question, In case you want me to do something else to clarify let me know.

Comment: @Sid See updated according to the question edit

Comment: awk and the first sed didn't work properly, However second version of sed did it but the output is distorted as in not aligned with tab, Most of the entries were fine, However few of them had a short Customer name so the tab space was not aligned, it was like

Cindy    Today
Victor    Today
Bob    Today
Martha   Tomorrow
Sam    Tomorrow

Also could you please explain the code?

Comment: @Sid 1)Your «didn't work properly» tells me nothing. I have check all scripts on example data: they work as required.2) For proper align pass the output via `| column -t`

Comment: Sorry for missing explanation. awk didn't give me Customer name, instead it gave me different sections of each schedule. I agree for the sample example it works perfect.
For your first sed, it gave me repeated entries for single customer with but just with Schedule name, again it worked perfect for example.
Bottom line last sed did the job perfect. What was the main difference?

Comment: Without data example which leads to mistake further research is void

Comment: One small query, I have using this code and it works fine in shell promt, However I tried to run it as a script to give the output to a file, it doesn't seem to work, Could you take a look?

for i in `cat /tmp/Active_Policies`
do
sudo ./policylist $i -U | sed -n '
    /Policy Name:/! d
    s/.*:\s\+//
    h
    :1
    n
    /Active:\s*no/d
    /HW\//!b1
    :2
    s/.*\s\(\S*\)\s*/\1/
    G
    s/\n/\t/p
    n
    /^\s*$\|Include:/! b2
    ' >> /tmp/Cust_Policies
done

Comment: I know the post has become huge, I need one small help from Costas. What wrong am I doing when I am trying to execute the code in a script file to direct output to a file?

Comment: @Sid >>Without data example which leads to mistake further research is void

Comment: I just need send the output a file, i used your code, However when I do it the file is empty.
same example in this a command policylist <schedule name> -U gives details of each policy one by one, So I have a file which has all schedule names and I am doing a for loop on the file where each schedule name goes through your sed command it works fine when i direct it to a file in shell menu, However it doesn't work when i use the whole command in a script file i don't know why.

Comment: Also it doesn't work on AIX, would it need any changes for it to work on AIX?

Comment: I am doing this as your code when I run it in a script file it doesn't work for some reason. But the code I am using runs pretty slow, I have mentioned the code in my question.

Comment: The Perl space expression `\s` and the `+` repetition operator are probably not supported on AIX, or generally portable. Try `[[:space:]]\+` and/or see if your `sed` supports an `-E` or `-r` option.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/Schedule/{A="";S=$NF;next}/Active/{A=$NF;next}/Customer/&&A=="yes"{print $NF,S}' billing
```